# MacBook Air MID 2012 Fan Control on Ubuntu 13.10 and higher

Tags: 13.10, macbook, fan, fancontrol, macbook-air

On my MacBook Air MID 2012 I use Ubuntu since 12.04.
After installing Ubuntu I had to install the "macfanctld" package (incl. configuration) to get the fan control of my MBA working. If not, the fan (exhaust) stays always on the minimum = 2000 rpm (maximum = 6000 rpm).

The ppa has only an update for (raring) Ubuntu 13.04. I asked the author of the package a view months ago if there is an 13.10 update planned, but I did not received an answer.

Here is the link to the ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=raring : It contains only a package for raring and not for saucy.

I installed the 13.04 package on my Ubuntu 13.10 but I am not sure if I should install the "old" package??

On 13.10 I installed it with the following commands:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list <<-EOF
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu raring main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu raring main 
EOF
sudo apt-get install macfanctld
```

Here is the link to the full script for 12.10: http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-ubuntu-12-10-in-macbook-air/ (see #6)

Is this package not necessary any more for Ubuntu 13.04 and higher ??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you: **I installed the 13.04 package on my Ubuntu 13.10 but I am not sure if I should install the "old" package??** What you installed and what is your problem then? What **old package** are you talking about? And also I would like to know how did you install **macfanctld** in Ubuntu **13.10**.

Comment: I modified the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following link solves my question/problem:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/ppa-install-fan-control-ubuntu-macbook/

Ubuntu 14.04:

> For Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, search for and install macfanctld package in Ubuntu Software Center after checking for updates.